# What is the longest and/or most expensive trip on an Opal card?

Tags: public-transport, australia, sydney, new-south-wales

What's the longest duration (actual travel, not waiting for connections), longest distance, or most expensive, trip that's available for free once 8 trips have been taken on an opal card?

A trip starting or finishing at one of the Sydney airport train stations doesn't count, because the free travel after 8 trips doesn't cover this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without getting into the philosophical paradoxes inherent in asking about "the most expensive free trip", I'm pretty sure the longest duration & distance that you can pull off with an Opal card in a single day without backtracking is **Goulburn, NSW to Scone, NSW by train**:

https://goo.gl/maps/6nYEY2oTjqT2

This clocks in at a cool **513.54 km** per the [official fare/distance calculator](http://www.sydneytrains.info/tickets/fare_calculator.htm) and would take you just short of 8 hours (**7h 57min**, to be precise) with a single connection at Central.

Farewise, though, any distance beyond 65 km is charged the same, so it's just **$8.30** for the whole trip.  Since Opal cards max out at **$15/day**, it's not possible to get more financial benefit than this out of *any* itinerary.  Because you're charged every time you transfer, it's quite easy to hit the $15 mark, even on much shorter journeys (say, Circular Quay-Manly return at $14.36 plus any trip anywhere).